# Puppeteer : how to pass argument to page evaluate?

Tags: javascript, async-await, parameter-passing, puppeteer

I want to pass an argument to Puppeteer `page evaluate` method.

I might just be  still struggling with async/await that I don't master,so my knowledge issue might be more general. Anyway Puppeteer is the current problem to be solved.

I have this snippet for updating a  element. It works well:

```
await page.evaluate(
    () =>
      (document.querySelector(
        "selector"
      ).innerHTML = "WHATEVER")
  );
```

"WHATEVER" value comes from an outside variable. I need to pass it along to evaluate.

I tried with :

```
const value = "WHATEVER"
async function setValue(val) {
    console.log(val) //OK
    await page.evaluate(
      () =>{
        console.log(val) // KO  Error [ReferenceError]: val is not defined
        document.querySelector(
          "selector"
        ).innerHTML = val
      }
    );
  }
  await setValue(value) // KO
```

Why is val not defined?
How to pass an argument to page evaluate in this case? Is there an alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`page.evaluate()` is isolated from the Node.js environment, which means it does not have access to variables from your Node.js script scope.
To pass an argument to the function you provide to `page.evaluate()`, you should include it as an additional parameter.
In fact this is the method signature:

```
page.evaluate(pageFunction, ...args);
```

So u need to so something like this:

```
const value = "WHATEVER"
async function setValue(val) {
    console.log(val) //OK
    await page.evaluate(
      (val) => {
        console.log(val) // Should be OK now
        document.querySelector("selector").innerHTML = val
      },
      val // This is where you're passing the argument 'val' to the function in page.evaluate()
    );
}
await setValue(value)
```

Comment: Thanks. I read the [Page evaluate signature](https://pptr.dev/api/puppeteer.page.evaluate), but didn't get it.